# Can't remove plugins from IOS project

Tags: cordova

When I create an app with the phonegap command line it automatically adds multiple plugins I don't want ..

```
plugin list
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.1.2 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.2 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.4 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.4 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 2.2.0 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.2.0 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.2 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
```

I can manually remove each one and if I do a another `plugin list` it is gone but if I build the project again `phonegap run ios` the plugin is reinstalled.

How do I create a project that does not install any plugins, or how do I remove these forever?

Process to create app ..

```
phonegap create helloworld com.example.helloworld helloWorld
phonegap platform add ios
phonegap run ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the project and find `config.xml` BEFORE you add a platform. Delete plugins from within `config.xml` then add your platform.